# Issue in Jenkins installation plugins

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins

I am facing issue while installing any of the Jenkins plugins suggested.

Actually after downloading,Jenkins.war file(which is latest 2.141) when i tried to execute the jar with
`java -jar jenkins.war` so it gave me an error of Jenkins require java 8 but you are using 10. Also,it says that java class version 54.0 is running,but it requires java 52.0.

But I was able to resolve this issue by setting `--enable-future-java flag`.

```
java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java flag
```

Now,after writing this command,jenkins is up and running but i am unable to install the plugins.
Also,im cmd prompt after the Jenkins is upa d running.There is one error also.
PFB :-

```
Sep 17, 2018 4:38:49 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
[31mSep 17, 2018 4:39:02 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
SEVERE: ERROR: SHA-512 based signature in the update center doesn&#039;t match with the certificate in &#039;update site &#039;default&#039;&#039;
[0mSep 17, 2018 4:39:02 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 15,407 ms
```

Comment: Just make sure you are using `oracle-jdk` and not `open-jdk`

Comment: I downgraded Java to version 1.8 and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a flag which allows starting Jenkins with unsupported Java versions. You can do some google research on this.

Comment: Hi - welcome to StackOverflow. This is a useful pointer, but as such it's not really a complete answer in itself: it would be a better answer if you could find that flag and edit it into your answer rather than telling people to find it themselves on Google, or linking to an off-site article. (In general if people only have a suggestion or incomplete answer they often post it as a comment on the question - rightly or wrongly - and I appreciate you can't do that yet as you don't have enough points to comment on other people's questions and answers yet.)

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

If we change the Jenkins war file version from 2.141 to 2.814 then it is suitable with Java 10 and works fine for plugins installation of Jenkins